# How can I open jQuery dialog window from C# in Asp.Net webforms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have as ASP.NET web form application, I need to open jQuery window from code behind based on certain logic (not click event of the button).
One way is to use Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript method, but is there a 'cleaner' way to do so ? I have to open different jQuery dialog windows at different places and capture the return values from the dialog windows. We also looked at a  couple of commercial frameworks but haven't made the decision yet.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way that codebehind can interact with javascript on the front end like that is to add javascript to the page. You could RegisterStartupScript, or put javascript text into a literal, but either way that's the type of approach you're looking at, if you want everything within the same page.

Alternatively, using ajax would allow you to post to a different page with javascript, without a full postback, and then open a dialog (or whatever) based on the return values of that request, but without knowing the details of your situation, I don't know if that's the type of solution you're looking for.